# Add data dynamically to an object recursively

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Given the following code:

```js
const data = {
  name: 'product',
  children: [
    { name: 'title' },
    { name: 'code' },
    { name: 'images', children: [{ name: 'image1' }, { name: 'image2' }] },
  ],
}


let result = {}

function resolveNodes(nodes, parentNode){
  if(nodes.children){
    parentNode = nodes.name;
    result[parentNode] = {};
    nodes.children.forEach(node => resolveNodes(node, parentNode));
  }else{
    result[parentNode][nodes.name] = nodes.name;
  }
}


resolveNodes(data);

console.log(result);
```

#### Current output

```
{
 product: {
 title:"title",
 code:"code"
},
images: {
 image1:"image1",
 image2:"image2"
}
}
```

#### Desired output:

```
{
 product: {
 title:"title",
 code:"code",
 images: {
  image1:"image1",
  image2:"image2"
  }
 }
}
```

I'm not sure how to recursively add a nested object within the parent (product) object. I've tried many things like passing the parent and the child to the function and from there try to work out the structure of the new object however it get very messy and I know is not the ideal way to do it.

This function will need to handle at least one extra layer of children but I've just added 2 to simplify the question.

What is the most ideal way to implement this?

Comment: the way the properties are merged and added between nested levels is inconsistent.  is product being at the same nesting level as title,code an exception, and the deeper nesting structure of images : {image  the correct structure afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and have a look to `children` and get a combined object, otherwise just the name as value.

Instead of giving a simplified solution, let's have a closer look to the code.

```
resolveNodes = ({ name, children }) => ({ [name]: children
    ? Object.assign(...children.map(resolveNodes))
    : name
})
```

The first part,

```
resolveNodes = ({ name, children }) =>
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the arguments of the function, contains a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), where an object is expected and from this object, the named properties are taken as own variables.

The following returned expression

```
resolveNodes = ({ name, children }) => ({ 

})
```

contains an object with a

```
                                          vvvvvvv
resolveNodes = ({ name, children }) => ({ [name]:


})
```

[computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), which takes the value of the variable as property name.

The following [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
                                                  children
    ? Object.assign(...children.map(resolveNodes))
    : name
```

checks `children`.

If this value is [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), like an array, it evaluates the part after `?` and if the value is *falsy*, the opposite of *truthy*, then it takes the expression after `:`.

In short, if no children, then take `name` as property value.

The part for truthy, if children exists,

```
      Object.assign(...children.map(resolveNodes))
```

returns a single object with all children properties.

```
      Object.assign(...children.map(resolveNodes))
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                create a single object
                    ^^^                            spread syntax
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^                return all element by using
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^   the actual function again
```

This part is easier to understand if order of execution is followed.

```
                       children.map(resolveNodes)
```

the inner part with a mapping of children by calling `resolveNodes` returns an array of objects with a single property. It looks like this

```
[
    { title: 'title' },
    { code: 'code' },
    { images:                  // this looks different, because nested 
        {                      // children are called first
            image1: 'image1',
            image2: 'image2'
        }
    }
]
```

and contains objects with a single property.

To get an single object with all properties of the array, [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) takes objects and combines all objects to one and replaces same properties in the target object with the latest following same named property. This is not the problem here, because all properties are different. Actually the problem is to take the array as parameters for calling the function.

This problem has two solutions, one is the old call of a function with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), like

```
Object.assign.apply(null, children.map(resolveNodes))
```

The other one and used

```
Object.assign(...children.map(resolveNodes))
```

is [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which takes an [*iterable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables) and adds the items as parameters into the function call.

```js
const
    resolveNodes = ({ name, children }) => ({ [name]: children
        ? Object.assign(...children.map(resolveNodes))
        : name
    }),
    data = { name: 'product', children: [{ name: 'title' }, { name: 'code' }, { name: 'images', children: [{ name: 'image1' }, { name: 'image2' }] }] },
    result = resolveNodes(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: **jnd0** still is a novice. I pretty much will appreciate if there was a second version, readable by/to beginners, of your highly compactly written, beautiful and efficient algorithm.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, i added some prosa. please see edit.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you so much for this detailed explanation. For me the biggest breakthroughs of this solutions are Object.assign and calling map taking the parameters from the spread operator.

Comment: Oh @NinaScholz, you kill me ;-) ... unfortunately I can show you my appreciation by upvoting your A. just once. But the biggest win is anyhow the comment from jnd0 that talks about gathering knew knowledge. Thanks a lot for all of your effort.

Comment: @NinaScholz you are genius. Well explained. Thanks!